# How to avoid reinitializing an expensive object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to load the same very large file from two different places, `A` and `B`, in my python library. However, this is a rather large library, and there's no easy way to pass an object from `A` to `B`. More specifically, I have a class like this:

```
class DistanceBetweenThings:
  def __init__(self):
    self.distance_matrix = load_huge_distance_matrix()
  def distance(self, a, b):
    return self.distance_matrix[a][b]
```

I want to be able to call this `distance()` function in two different places in the code. But I don't want to pass a `DistanceBetweenThings` object through my entire codebase. But I also don't want to call `load_huge_distance_matrix()` more than once. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Make it a class attribute.

Comment: "However, this is a rather large library, and there's no easy way to pass an object from A to B. More specifically," um, that doesn't really make sense. You should be using dependency injection anyway, especially i your project is "rather large".

Comment: @KlausD. well, but then the problem shifts to passing around the class object...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You don't need to pass classes around to keep a class attribute alive. Every new instance of the class will have the same initialized attribute.

Comment: @KlausD. well, you don't need to pass an instance around either, you can just make it a global variable and use the method/attribute you need, which is essentially what the class variable would be used as here. Again, the point I'm trying to make is you should be using dependency injection, not relying on global state like that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Considring that the text leaves room for interpretation, I'm not sure if we are both answering the same question.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your `distance_matrix` a class attribute, it will be initialized **once** at import time:

```
class DistanceBetweenThings:
    distance_matrix = load_huge_distance_matrix()

    def distance(self, a, b):
        return self.distance_matrix[a][b]
```

Now you can create a new instance of the class and do your `distance` call anywhere in your code. Just the class has to imported.

```
DistanceBetweenThings().distance(a, b)
```

Comment: ... therefore making imports slower. And might not be good idea for large projects as OP said. At the very least, I'd suggest a classmethod to load things so people can control *when* it loads.

Comment: @UltraInstinct making imports slower? Why?

Comment: @UltraInstinct It is going to make exactly one import slower: the initial one. In the end it is always a balance between speed and memory. There's the choice to safe memory by loading and discarding the data every time, or to safe speed by loading the data once and storing it in memory.

Comment: Yes, I meant the just initial import and all I meant to suggest was to keep imports free of heavy operations and instead call a `@classmethod` that actually loads it. That way, 1) The matrix can be loaded when you want; instead of being dictated to you by when you initially import, 2) (personal preference) explicit over implicit when reading the app startup code.  As for your latter half, obviously I understand it and it's the point of the question. :)